# How to remove flex hose from a single-control, tall faucet?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet

I have a faucet that is leaking down the flex hose. The one flex hose unscrewed easily. The second is turning but not coming out. I assume the nut has become separated from the crimp on the hose. There's no way to get a wrench on the nut. Does anyone know a trick to remove this hose?

[image: Faucet]

[image: Flex hose in faucet![][2]]

[image: Flex hose removed]

I don't know the faucet manufacturer, there are no identifying marks.

Comment: There is probably an intentional swivel fitting inside, not the best location for one. I'm not familiar with this fixture, but I would guess you can remove the valve body and attached hose after removing the cartridge from the top.